# Cordova build For Windows

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-cli

I am successfully able to build for android, now I want to build apps for windows.

What is the process of setting up the build environment for windows?

I do not want to work with Visual Studio, can I install windows SDK as a stand alone and work with it using the command line?

If I take a look at the Docs here it does not go into any detail
https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows

The same is mentioned here as well https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html

If I have no way of escaping the use of Visual Studio, then kindly also mention the correct way to install the tools for Cordova Development

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your issue with Visual Studio?  Visual Studio community is free and Microsoft's TACO (Tools for Apache COrdova) is amazing. Ultimately, you can use the Cordova CLI to create and manage a project, but you'll need tools from Microsoft to compile the resulting app.

I'm not aware that you can install the Windows SDK without Visual Studio, I've not tried it. Apparently you can though: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk.

Just in case you want complete instructions for setting up and using a Windows development environment for Cordova, you can find them in chapter 11 of Apache Cordova 4 Programming (www.cordova4programming.com).

Comment: I haven't used visual studio and am more comfortable with a text editor rather than an IDE...However i had to install VS community and from there I installed the build tools..Now I am able to build windows apps..Thanks

Comment: Microsoft discontinued the support for Cordova projects with Visual Studio 2019. It seems that @krv's prejudice regarding the complicated IDE was really on spot.