# Is there really no way, to be able to build/debug cordova and uap apps for Windows 10 from commandline only?

Tags: android, windows, cordova, win-universal-app

I was searching through many questions, but found no solution that would suite my needs.

What I want is to [use Windows SDK 10 for building/debugging UAP and Cordova apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268545/cordova-build-for-windows), but without need to use Visual Studio.
I use other IDE, IntelliJ IDEA precisely, so VS is just another piece of software which isn't quite desirable.

I'm working on a project, that must be built with cordova to use it on Android and Windows 10 Mobile.
But, it should be possible to build mostly from commandline with as less requirements regarding additional software (like IDE tools for building and debugging) as possible.
Just plain commandline.

Building for first platform from cmd works sweet, because it uses SDK which don't requires no heavy IDEs.
But, AFAIK, on Windows 10 for UAP and Cordova apps, at least VS2015 is a must.

Are there no standalone TACO tools, that can work outside Visual Studio?

Cheers!

Comment: AFAIK you only need to install the windows uwp sdk with the visual studio installation. After the install you can build and run windows uwp apps through cli commands

Comment: Maybe I've found the solution by myself, it's called [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).
This and Windows 10 SDK probably should suffice it, but I have to try it.

But, do I need Windows 10 SDK with similar build version as my development environment (laptop and lumia 550)?
Thus, they both run on Windows 10, version: 1607, OS build: 10.0.14393, where laptop OS build is 10.0.14393.187 and lumia OS build is 10.0.14393.1066.

IMO, SDK version 10.0.14393.0 should work for both compilations, right?

Comment: Even if you find that you have to install Visual Studio for some reason or other, you don't *have* to use the IDE.